# JQUERY HASH + how pass extra variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://www.domainname.com/#changepassword

I need to pass an extra variable with a URL like above.

I've tried a few ways but I'm unsure of the best way to do this eg:

http://www.domainname.com/#changepassword?variable

I'm using the following JQUERY to catch the HASH:

```
if (window.location.hash != '') {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    if(hash == 'changepassword') {      // Password Change
        alert('changepassword');
    }
}
```

How can I pass an extra variable with the HASH? Best method to capture the HASH and extra variable.

thx

Comment: there is **no** jQuery in your code example ... thats plan JavaScript

Comment: but having `jQuery` tag will make the scope to answer in jQuery. And the `jQuery` people who avoid `javascript` tags will see it highlighted !

Comment: @tusar I wasn't questioning the need for the tag (I would have edited and removed it if i thought it was out of place) - I was merely stating facts ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing the `location.hash` with `location.search` - [see here for the explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

You could use just the `location.hash` and put a seperator between your "variables" :

For example .. if this was your url  `http://www.domainname.com/#changepassword-variable-another` then you could do

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
var hasharray = hash.split['-']
if(hasharray[0] == 'changepassword') {      // Password Change
    alert('changepassword');
}
```

or you could use the `location.search` and the following example :

URL : `http://www.domainname.com/?command=changepassword&var=variable&var2=another`

this uses the `key=value` format, then use the following method to access the `values`

```
function getQueryString() {
  var result = {}, queryString = location.search.substring(1),
      re = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m;

  while (m = re.exec(queryString)) {
    result[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
  }

  return result;
}
```

You can then get the values by passing the function your `key`

```
var command = getQueryString()["command"];
if(command == 'changepassword') {      // Password Change
    alert('changepassword');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the jQuery URL plugin instead of making the parsing by yourself:  https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser

Answer (score 0):

```
"#ffsf?sdff?sffsfd".match(/(?!\?)\w+/g)
```

result :

```
["ffsf", "sdff", "sffsfd"] // Array
```

Anyway , you should be more precise on what you intend to do.